# How can i add a BehaviourScript to an Instantiated GameObject in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Game, where you can Instantiate Cubes with your left Mouse Button. Now i want to rotate these Instantiated Cubes with the Arrow Keys. I would like to know, how i could connect the Code below, with my Instantiated Cube!
(My Instantiated Cubes are beeing saved in a List btw.)

My Code for the Rotations:

```
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotationAngle * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, - rotationAngle * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put that code in a script and name it something like RotateOnKeys and then in your script that Instantiates the cubes do something like this:

```
// This is the line of code that you're already using to spawn a cube:
GameObject cube = GameObject.Instantiate(cubePrefab) as GameObject;

// This is the line of code needed to attach a script:
cube.AddComponent<RotateOnKeys>();
```

Comment: Not exactly what i expected, but it worked :) Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

There's several ways to do it, as with most programming-related things.

First, you want to put this in a MonoBehaviour.  Specifically, you probably want it in the Update() loop.  Something like this:

```
public class SpinGameObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotationAngle * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, - rotationAngle * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want this on all of your cubes, you can attach it directly to your prefab which is being instantiated.

Otherwise, if you want to be selective about what cubes to apply it to, you could get your instantiated GameObject which contains your cube, and then call the following function:

```
void AttachScriptToGameObject(GameObject go)
{
    go.AddComponent<SpinGameObject>();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Edit:
Lots of people responding, all of these work :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are looking for something called **Prefab**. **Prefab** is premade object, you can add scripts to it etc. and then you can just instantiate this **prefab**.  A [**prefab** tutorial link](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/editor/prefabs-concept-usage)

edit

Or you can do it @Jayson Ash way.